# javascript functions stop working after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code is below:

```
<div id="action-buttons" class="container">
     <button type="button" name="MyButton" id="closeButton">close RMA</button>
</div>
<div>
<button type="button" id="refreshButtons">refresh Buttons</button>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#refreshButtons").on('click', function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/renderButtons.html",
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Error message');
                        },
                        success: function (HtmlResult) {
                            $("#action-buttons").html(HtmlResult);
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            alert('Action buttons - loaded successfully');
                        }

                    });

                });


                $("#closeButton").on('click', function () {
                    alert('some text');
                });



            });
    </script>
```

When i click on `#closeButton` I see the Alert. That's correct.

But when I load the `div#action-buttons` content (by clicking `#refreshButtons`) my alert doesn't show. Why?

Why there is no message in browser console?.

"/renderButtons.html" is simply html file:

```
<button type="button" name="MyButton" id="closeButton">close RMA</button>
```

Comment: your alert will apear on click on #closeButton not #refreshButtons

Comment: Why you're replacing the button at all if its the same markup again?

Comment: @Andreas: This is only the example of my problem, real code is too huge to paste here.

Answer (score 4):

The buttons stop triggering the event handler because they're not hooked up to it (anymore).

Your

```
$("#action-buttons").html(HtmlResult);
```

line **completely destroys** the elements inside the `#action-buttons` element and **replaces** them with new elements. Those new elements are not hooked up to your event handler, the old one were.

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Hook them up again
2. Use event delegation

Event delegation is probably want you want here. You hook the event on a container that won't be changed (`#action-buttons`, for instance), but tell jQuery not to call your handler unless the event passed through an element matching a selector you give it:

```
$("#action-buttons").on('click', "#closeButton", function () {
    alert('some text');
});
```

More in the [`on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on).

**Live Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter = 0;
  $("#refreshButtons").on('click', function() {
    // Simulating the ajax here
    setTimeout(function() {
        ++counter;
        $("#action-buttons").html(
          '<button type="button" name="MyButton" id="closeButton">close RMA #' + counter + '</button>'
        );
    }, 10);
  });


  $("#action-buttons").on('click', "#closeButton", function() {
    alert('some text');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="action-buttons" class="container">
  <button type="button" name="MyButton" id="closeButton">close RMA</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" id="refreshButtons">refresh Buttons</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After Ajax response; your existing button is getting removed and newer button is getting inserted in DOM. So whatever `events` you had bounded to your older button gets automatically removed from context. So deal with such situation you need to use jquery's event delegation technique while attaching event as follows:

```
$(document).on('click',"#closeButton", function () {
    alert('some text');
});
```

In above case; event first gets attached and listen by `document` and then it gets delegated to button with an id "#closeButton" if that is present in DOM. I hope I have cleared your doubt.